# ajax code contains "PHP site_url" with parameters in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to ask, is it possible, if the ajax code contains "*PHP site_url*" with *parameters in ajax*

this is the specific code:

```
"<a class='btn btn-info' href="<?php 'echo site_url("data_detail/detail_datas/vieworc/ " + item.NIK + "); '?>">Detail</a>"
```

this is the full code:

```
                 .done(function(dt){
                        if(dt != null){
                            console.log(dt)
                            table.rows().remove().draw();
                            $.each(dt, function(i, item){
                                table.row.add([
                                    item.Name,
                                    item.NIK,
                                    item.gender,
                                    item.PositionDesc,
                                    item.Shift,
                                    item.tgl,
                                    item.Attendance,
                                   "<a class='btn btn-info' href="<?php 'echo site_url("data_detail/detail_datas/vieworc/ " + item.NIK + "); '?>">Detail</a>"
                                ]).draw();
                            })
                        }
                    })
                });
```

Comment: No, try to pass the logic to frontend

Comment: You'll need to remove the `item.NIK` part from the PHP code.

Comment: @Phil : yes, but, i need "ITEM.NIK" to included on site_url to move page in accordance with the NIK

Comment: @lay : yes, but, i need "ITEM.NIK" to included on site_url to move page in accordance with the NIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
"<button type='button' class='btn btn-success' onclick='showDetail(\""+ item.NIK + "\");' >Detail</button>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `site_url()` only concats strings, you can do something like this:

```
// Pass the result as a js variable
const siteUrlTpl = "<?php echo site_url('data_detail/detail_datas/vieworc/{NIK}'); ?>";
// ...
.done(function(dt){
    if(dt != null){
        console.log(dt)
        table.rows().remove().draw();
        $.each(dt, function(i, item){
            table.row.add([
                item.Name,
                item.NIK,
                item.gender,
                item.PositionDesc,
                item.Shift,
                item.tgl,
                item.Attendance,
                // Replace the {NIK} to the real value
                "<a class='btn btn-info' href='" + siteUrlTpl.replace('{NIK}', item.NIK) + "'>Detail</a>"
            ]).draw();
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: thank's for help, but i found error,, the error : 


3:419 Uncaught ReferenceError: siteUrlTpl is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (3:419)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (3:409)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)